# Customizing filter in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Spreadsheet for work purposes but I can't get it the way I want. If I do it in Excel it works but I can't match it in Google Spreadsheet. I don't even know if it's possible. (See pictures below.)

When I filter in Excel, it breaks it down as "2016", "2015", etc. Each year I can click and they have the months in those years. Can this be done in Google Sheets?

Google Spreadsheet:
[image: Google Spreadsheet]

Excel (how I want it):
[image: Excel]

Answer (score 1):

The filter in Google Sheets does not have this sort of tree selector for dates. Some alternatives:

1. To display only the records from a particular year, select "Filter by condition" -> "Text ends with" -> 2014 (or some other year).
2. To display only records within some period, select "Filter by condition" -> "Is between" -> start date, end date (for example, 5/1/15 and 5/31/15).

There are also some built-in conditions under Date is... such as "in the past month", "in the past year", etc.